# How to write "pera" instead of "Result is" when num1 and num2 are empty? I've tried myself but every time i get "Result is"

Tags: php, math

I want to write **pera** instead of **Result is: ...** when `num1` and `num2` are empty. I tried the following code but didn't get the wanted result.

What did I do wrong ?

```
function math() {
    $total="";

    $getoption=$_POST['option'];
    if ($getoption==="sabiranje") {
        $total=$_POST['num1']+$_POST['num2'];
    } elseif ($getoption==="oduzimanje") {
        $total=$_POST['num1']-$_POST['num2'];
    } elseif ($getoption==="mnozenje") {
        $total=$_POST['num1']*$_POST['num2'];
    } elseif ($getoption==="deljenje") {
        if ($_POST['num2']==0 ) {
            $_POST['num2']=1;
            $total="Nije moguce deliti sa 0";
        } else {
            $total=$_POST['num1']/$_POST['num2'];
        }
    } 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['num1']=null || $_POST['num2']=null) {
            echo "pera";
        } else {
            echo "Result is: " . $total . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting `pera`, since you're using the wrong equals. You're using the single equal/assignment operator instead of the double/triple equals comparison operators.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using assign operator instead of comparing.it must be like that :

```
if ($_POST['num1'] == null || $_POST['num2'] == null)
```